# Angular - Failing to open Post response which a PDF file

Tags: angular

I want to view the PDF file which is my post response, below is my post code, Any help

```
printQuotation(quote: Quotes) {
    const requestBody = {
      quotationId: quote.quotationId,
      vehicleRegistration: quote.vehicleRegistration,
      insurerId: quote.insurerId,
      insurer: quote.insurer,
      calculationResponse:quote.calculationResponse,
      addOns: quote.addOns,
    };
    this.printService.postToUrl('/quotations-print', requestBody,).subscribe(

      {
      next: (res) => {
        this.printOption=true;
        
      },
    }
    )

  }
```

Comment: You might want to specifiy what the issue is. Does it even reach the subscribe block? Or is an error returned? It also wouldn't hurt to add your service code.

Comment: @AldinBradaric The issue is about to download the PDF file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want add 'blob' to request header :

```
 postToUrl(url,data = null,params = null,responseType = null,){

      return this.http.post(url, data, {
      params,
      responseType,
    });}
```

and on the function calling part also pass the 'blob' as reponseType

```
printQuotation(quote: Quotes) {
const requestBody = {
  quotationId: quote.quotationId,
  vehicleRegistration: quote.vehicleRegistration,
  insurerId: quote.insurerId,
  insurer: quote.insurer,
  calculationResponse:quote.calculationResponse,
  addOns: quote.addOns,
};
this.printService.postToUrl('/quotations-print', requestBody,null,'blob').subscribe(

  {
  next: (res) => {
    this.printOption=true;
    
  },
}
)}
```

if not work please let me know...

**NB: you want to send the pdf as blob data**

Comment: Is the above solution worked?

Comment: I managed to solve using kendo-file-saver

Comment: OK that's nice.